# "_" parameter of Ruby block

Tags: ruby, zentest

I met this when I read ZenTest source code:

Here is the definition of add_mapping method:

```
def add_mapping(regexp, &proc)
  @test_mappings << [regexp, proc]
end
```

In the `Autottest.initailize()`, `add_method` get called to add mapping for implementations.

```
self.add_mapping(/^lib\/.*\.rb$/) do |filename, _|
  possible = File.basename(filename).gsub '_', '_?'
  files_matching %r%^test/.*#{possible}$%
end
```

My question is what "_", the second parameter of the block, means? Seems it is not used in the block.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an idiom used to indicate the the parameter bound to '_' is not used, even though it's required to be passed to the block/method.

example:

```
def blah
   yield 1,2
end

blah {|a,b|
  puts a
  # b is never used
}
```

compare to the identical:

```
blah {|a,_|
   puts a
}
```

Note that '_' is a perfectly legal variable name in ruby, so the two versions are identical, the following works as well:

```
blah {|a,_|
   puts _
}
```

Using '_' is nothing more than a convention like using `i` for counters, 'x' and 'y' or 'foo' and 'bar'.

It means you're cool because you've been dabbling with functional programming, which is, I believe, where this idiom orignates...

Comment: @a2800276, could you please show me some tutorials or resources about this "_" idiom?

Comment: There aren't any tutorials, it's just an idiom, common usage. It's just a variable name like any other (I've edited the ost to make that clearer) Google 'functional programming pattern matching wildcard' if you want to check out the origin.

Answer (score 4):

```
def animals
  yield "Tiger"
  yield "Giraffe"
end
animals { |_| puts "Hello, #{_}" }
```

Example stolen from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Ruby_Basics

As far as I can see, it's defining _ as a variable which could be referenced later on. This is just forcing ruby's hand and defining _ as to the value of whatever is yielded.

Comment: @Radar, I could understand your example. But why "_" in my question reference the result of the block? How exactly the sequence of the add_method call is? As I understand, the "_" should be reference to the "filename" variable.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the author is using it as a short variable name so that the second parameter can be ignored.

Comment: Do you mean the "_" here can be replaced by any variable name?

Comment: That's right, I think. Since it's not being used, it doesn't matter.

Comment: This is correct. _ is common in many languages for a variable name that doesn't see explicit use. It means "ignore me"